# Makefile is acceptable only for reading

Tags: makefile

I created a makefile, made some entries and saved. Then in a while I founded out the file is opened only for reading, in spite of my writing right for it is available. I tried to re-set the rights entering `chmod -c u+wrx [file path]` and then `ls -l [file path]` for reviewing and it didn`t use to change anything!

Comment: Please show the permissions on the file in your question.  As it stands there's no way we can diagnose the problem or provide assistance.

Comment: `ls -l` outputs rights for owner (me): -rwxr

Comment: Do you get the message from vim/vi ? If you did not close a vim session, vim will warn about the file being in use - usually using a ".swp" file in the same folder. Check (with ps) for vim session, and for ".swp" file.

Comment: I use Kate editor, not Vim.

Comment: When you say "opened only for reading", you mean in your editor?  Probably your editor is not checking the filesystem again to notice that the permissions have changed.  Maybe you can find a way to tell your editor to check it again.  Or maybe you have to re-load that file into your editor.

Comment: In any event, this has nothing to do with make or makefiles.  If this was a source file rather than a makefile you'd have the same issue no doubt.  Please change the tag on your question to refer to your editor instead, since that's where the problem is.